# Are the other methods to pass values from a text file to create a basic log-in system in java?

Tags: java, swing, io, awt, project

I need to create a basic log-in system using a text file in `java.AWT` and/or `javax.SWING`.

Using the `BufferedReader` in the console application makes it work, but when I use the same process in the GUI (`Swing`) it is totally a mess. My `JTextField`s values don't match with the value in the text file.

Are there any possible ways to create a log-in system using a text file other than using io classes.  Here is my code.

```
public class VotingSystemLogin extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    //initialize io constructors
    static int checkAcc = 0;
    static int checkAcc2 = 0;
    static int checkTotal;
    //initialize and construct components
    JButton loginBtn = new JButton ("LOGIN");
    JButton regBtn = new JButton ("REGISTER");
    JLabel idLbl = new JLabel ("StudentID:");
    JTextField studIdTxt = new JTextField (5);;
    JLabel nameLbl = new JLabel ("StudentName:");
    JTextField studNameTxt = new JTextField (5);
    JLabel nameLayoutLbl = new JLabel ("(e.g. Juan dela Cruz)");
    JLabel idLayoutLbl = new JLabel ("(e.g. 063-2013-0001)");
    JLabel bgLbl = new JLabel ("bg");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    Container con = getContentPane();

    String sID = studIdTxt.getText();
    String sName = studNameTxt.getText();

    public VotingSystemLogin() {
        super("Login");
        //adjust size and set layout and location
        setSize(380, 230);
        setLocation(530,290);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.setLayout (null);
        panel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(10,10,10,10,Color.blue));

        //add components

        panel.add(loginBtn);
        panel.add(regBtn);
        panel.add(idLbl);
        panel.add(studIdTxt);
        panel.add(nameLbl);
        panel.add(studNameTxt);
        panel.add(nameLayoutLbl);
        panel.add(idLayoutLbl);
        //panel.add(bgLbl);
        try{
            BufferedImage loginLogo = ImageIO.read(new File("loginBg.jpg"));
            bgLbl = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(loginLogo));
            panel.add(bgLbl);
            bgLbl.setBounds (15, 10, 340, 180);
        }
        catch(IOException a)
        {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
        con.add(panel);

        //set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)
        loginBtn.setBounds (70, 140, 115, 40);
        regBtn.setBounds (210, 140, 115, 40);
        idLbl.setBounds (70, 35, 60, 35);
        studIdTxt.setBounds (155, 40, 170, 20);
        nameLbl.setBounds (70, 85, 80, 25);
        studNameTxt.setBounds (155, 85, 170, 20);
        nameLayoutLbl.setBounds (155, 105, 170, 15);
        idLayoutLbl.setBounds (155, 60, 120, 15);

        //add actionlisterner to buttons
        loginBtn.addActionListener(this);

    }


    public static void main (String[] args) {
        VotingSystemLogin vsl = new VotingSystemLogin();

    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

        if (e.getSource() == loginBtn)
        {
            checkVoters();
            checkVoted();

            checkTotal = checkAcc + checkAcc2;

            System.out.println(checkAcc);
            System.out.println(checkAcc2);
            System.out.println(checkTotal);

            if (checkTotal == 2)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have already voted!","Fail",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            else if (checkTotal == 1)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You may vote now!","Success",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"StudentID or StudentName is incorrect or doesn't exist","Fail",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public void checkVoters(){

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try{
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("voters.txt"));

            String id1 = br.readLine();
            String name1 = br.readLine();

            while (id1 != null && name1 != null){
                System.out.println(id1);
                System.out.println(name1);
                id1 = br.readLine();
                name1 = br.readLine();
                if (sID.equals(id1) && sName.equals(name1)){
                    checkAcc = 1;
                }
            }

            System.out.println();

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException a){
                a.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException a){
                a.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                if (br != null){
                    try{
                        br.close();
                    }
                    catch(IOException a){
                        a.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }   
    }

    public void checkVoted(){
        BufferedReader br2 = null;

        try{
            br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("voted.txt"));

            String id2 = br2.readLine();
            String name2 = br2.readLine();

            while (id2 != null && name2 != null){
                System.out.println(id2);
                System.out.println(name2);
                if (sID.equals(id2) && sName.equals(name2)){
                    checkAcc2 = 1;
                }
                id2 = br2.readLine();
                name2 = br2.readLine();

            }

            System.out.println();

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException a){
                a.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException a){
                a.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                if (br2 != null){
                    try{
                        br2.close();
                    }
                    catch(IOException a){
                        a.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you mean by 'using notepad'.   Do you mean you need a better way to handle checking the voters rather than reading a file named 'voters.txt'?  If that's the case, then, Yes, you could be querying a database using the voter id  and checking their status

Comment: What I mean is if there are other methods to be used in scanning through notepad? Because we are not yet required to used databases. Notepad will be our temporary database.

Comment: Take a look at Property object within Java.  They have a key=value format for each line.  Comments start with #.  You can easily load() the file from disk and then do get(key) to retrieve the value.  Null returned if not found.  Not sure what the format of your voters.txt file is/was -  I didn't look that closely.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually assign a valid value to `sID` or `sName`...Basically you just assign what ever was set as the default value to the `JTextField`s when they were created...

```
String sID = studIdTxt.getText();
String sName = studNameTxt.getText();
```

This means when you come to check the values against what's in the files, you're not actually comparing what's currently in the fields...

Remember, GUI's are event driven environments, something happens, you respond to it...

What you should be doing is, when the `actionPerformed` is called, you should get the text from the fields...

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

    if (e.getSource() == loginBtn)
    {
        sID = studIdTxt.getText();
        sName = studNameTxt.getText();
```

What would be better is if your check methods actually required you to pass the values you want checked instead of relying on instance values.

And yes, there are better solutions than dealing with files, a standalone database like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) (for example) would be a much better idea.

Comment: my problem now is whenever I log-in it always falls into my if statement even though it should fall into my else if. Are there other ways to read and pass values from notepad? Thanks for the help.

Comment: or should I ask it this way? Is there another way of reading and checking a textfile per line? Because whenever I print the values of variable "id" it prints the whole texts in the file.

Comment: I would depend on how your file is formatted, you could also use XML

Comment: no need as of now because I already answered my own question. By the way, thanks a lot with the help :-)